# After getting new router, I intermittently lose DNS

Tags: networking, router, dns

I just switched from Comcast's rental modem/router to my own Motorola SURFboard modem/router SBG6580. Since then, I am unable to load webpages at unexpected intervals (could be minutes, could be hours). The page hangs with message "Resolving host", then fails with "DNS probe finished, no internet" (running Chrome on Mac OSX 10.10.1 Yosemite).

My router's dns servers are set to Comcast's (75.75.75.75 and 75.75.76.76) and apparently I can't change them (https://support.opendns.com/entries/57906910-Motorola-SURFboard-SBG-6580)

I tried changing my dns servers on my Mac directly (To Google's, 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4), but still had random moments where it could not resolve dns.

Comment: Do you have the old one still on the network?

Comment: Are your internal devices set to use the router as their DNS server or are they using the external DNS? Whichever it is, try switching. I'd wager that your devices are using the router as their immediate DNS and it is having problems delivering results.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing DNS probe finished no internet error, then I recommend you to first clean your browser's history and also reboot your router. You can also refer a solution of this problem here:

http://laptopify.com/fix-dns-probe-finished-no-internet-error/

Comment: Can you please cite the pertinent steps related to the solution found at that web page?  Hyperlinks can "break" and render the proposed solution useless.  Thanks for your help!